# What programming language does facebook use?

Tags: facebook, programming-languages

I don't know much about programming languages, but am interested in a career with facebook, so I was wondering if someone could tell me what programming language facebook uses.

Also, do any other social networking sites use the same language?

Comment: You can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_languages_used_in_most_popular_websites

Answer (score 24):

Facebook uses the LAMP stack, so if you want to get a career with them you're going to want to focus on that. In addition they often have C++ and/or Java listed in their requirements as well.

One of the postings includes the following requirements:

- Expertise with C++ and/or Java
- Knowledge of Perl or PHP or Python
- Knowledge of relational databases and SQL, preferably MySQL and Oracle

Another:

- Expertise in PHP, JavaScript, and
  CSS.

Another:

- Knowledge of Perl or PHP or Python
- Knowledge of relational databases and
- SQL, preferably MySQL Knowledge of
- web technologies: XHTML, JavaScript
  Experience with C, C++ a plus

### Source

http://www.facebook.com/careers/#!/careers/department.php?dept=engineering

> Also, do any other social networking sites use the same language?

**Some other companys that use PHP/LAMP Stack:**

- [DeviantArt](http://deviantart.theresumator.com/apply/8ZGsSA/Senior-Web-Application-Developer.html) (more focused on art)
- [Twitter](http://twitter.com/job.html?jvi=owPbVfwb,Job) (for Front-End development)
- [Google+](http://www.google.com/intl/en/jobs/uslocations/mountain-view/swe/software-engineer-google-com-mountain-view/index.html)

Comment: AFAIK, twitter uses a custom in house object store written in scala for data access, google uses bigtable, and facebook uses cassandra. So pretty much just swap out MySQL for NoSQL

Comment: Yeah, they're all variants of the LAMP stack, just replacing the database portion, but leaves his core question about language in place.

Comment: Google only allow their developers to write projects in java/python/c++/javascript. Twitter use Ruby on Rails for the front end.

Comment: @Pedro I specifically put postings where PHP is required

Comment: They just launched Hack http://hacklang.org/ They claim they are already using it for facebook.com for over a year. It's very close to php but a bit closer to statically typed languages.

Answer (score 13):

Since nobody has mentioned it, I'd like to add that Facebook chat is written in [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/).

Answer (score 7):

The language used by Facebook is [PHP](http://www.php.net/).

> Also, do any other social networking
>   sites use the same language?

The other one I know of is [friendster](http://www.friendster.com/).

Answer (score 5):

might be surprised to know.. its PHP.  read all about it [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/)

Comment: Cos. I had an idea that PHP would never scale.. :-)

Comment: that link is too limited ..says mysql store data as key value pair.-1