# Uploading Files with Jquery before Form Submit - Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, form-submit

We Typically attach a files with a HTML File input and submit the form to the server with Content-Type=multipart/form-data.

However in modern way now the files start to upload via jquery ajax as soon as we select and after this the form is posted.

So what is best approach to achieve the above action at client side as well as getting the posted file at server when form is submitted to the controller action?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want before submit button click getting the posted file at server.

You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005678/how-to-upload-an-image-with-jquery-client-side-and-add-it-to-a-div)

Comment: Actually you can see on facebook before you post your status your selected photos/videos start making upload progress

Comment: In that case refer facebook language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690092/what-programming-language-does-facebook-use

Comment: That is not help ful